# How to get the contents of a docker container (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a simple `Dockerfile` where I create a pandas data frame and write it to a csv. The csv is saved inside the docker container and I want to extract it to my local directory. When I try to get the contents with `docker cp` it says that there is no such container. Here is my docker file:

```
# User an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir -p results
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

and here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
print('The Mean of x is {}'.format(x.mean()))
np.save('results/test', x)

print('Testing Pandas')
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print(df)
df.to_csv('results/test_df.csv')
```

I build the file:

```
docker build -t testing .
```

then:

```
docker run testing
```

when I try to extract the csv I am unable to do so. I would really appreciate any help or comments.

Comment: What command did you use for `docker cp` post the complete command